# Python Splinter browser = Browser() not working

Tags: python, splinter

I am trying to use splinter to test my webapp. When I try to execute the following

```
>>> from splinter import Browser
>>> browser = Browser()
```

I get this error. I have been looking around but I'm not sure how to fix.
Could someone please tell me how to get past this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/danny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/danny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/firefox.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.driver = Firefox(firefox_profile)
  File "/Users/danny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/Users/danny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/danny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 67, in launch_browser
    self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
  File "/Users/danny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 90, in _start_from_profile_path
    env=self._firefox_env)
  File "/Users/danny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Users/danny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

Comment: Is that the full callstack?  I'm not seeing the actual error message.

Comment: sorry, the final line is:
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: thanks guys, im stupid sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code from `firefox_binary.py` that is throwing: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py#L79-L90

Do you have Firefox installed and working properly?  I would also try updating Firefox to make sure it's on the latest version.